# RegEx in JavaScript is not working as expected basd on external validators

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the javascript regular expression editor located here:  [Scriptular](http://scriptular.com/) which is working as intended so I *think* my RegEx is good but I did just start working and learning with RegEx so I might be off on the way I implemented the RegEx with JS.

**Plan:**  The user fills in a form and the value entered is then evaluated to determine if it is an email address or a UID (user id).  If email, we accept it as long as it passes a fairly simple RegEx.  If it doesn't pass that, then we evaluate the form field to see if it is a valid format for a UID (we do more checks on this later) and if both fail, we send an alert to the user stating that the value entered is not accepted as a valid email or UID.  This is the goal.  It is for internal use only so with aren't trying to throw every possible email test against it and as for UID, the RegEx below has been working for us thus far.

*1 represents when I enter john.doe@gmail.com

2 represents when ab1234 is entered*

```
for (var i=0,max=tagArray.length;i<max;i++) {    
    var n = tagArray[i];    
    var uid_regex = /^[a-z]{2}\d{3}[a-z0-9]{1}$/i;  
    var email_regex = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i;
    var email_eval  = n.match(email_regex);    
    var uid = n.match(uid_regex);    
    console.log(n + ' evaluates to (email/uid): ' + email_eval + ' and ' + uid);    
    //1 log shows when john.doe@gmail.com is entered: john.doe@gmail.com evaluates to (email/uid): john.doe@gmail.com and null 
    //2 log shows when ab1234 is entered: ab1234 evaluates to (email/uid): null and ab1234
    if ((uid = null) && ( email_eval != null)){    
        //  $("##scheduleDist").tagit("createTag", n);    
        console.log('The value entered is an email address: ' + email_eval);    
    }    
    else if ((uid != null) && ( email_eval = null)){    
        console.log('The value entered is a UID: ' + n);    
    }    
    else {    
        console.log( n + ' is not a valid entry. Email Validation: ' + email_eval + '    UID Validation: ' + uid );    
        //1 log shows: john.doe@gmail.com is not a valid entry. Email Validation: john.doe@gmail.com    UID Validation: null
        //2 log shows:  ab1234 is not a valid entry. Email Validation: null    UID Validation: null             
    return false;    
}
```

***NOTE:***  In trying to format it for SO, I hopefully did not mess up the script.  There are not JS errors dispalyed in FF or IE or Chrome so if there is a syntax error her, it was because of my formatting.

At the risk of biasing people's answers, I do believe my problem is on line 10 and/or line 14 (the if and else if conditional lines).

If I did not make something clear, please let me know.

TIA,
Tom

Comment: This email won't validate (as well as many others) with that regex: `elclanrs@domain.museum`

Comment: LOL  *It is for internal use only so with aren't trying to throw every possible email test against it* but thanks though.

Comment: Oh, missed that part, in that case that should do xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ((uid = null) ...`

This sets `uid` to null, and "returns" null (the value assigned), therefore causing your statement to always fail.

Use `==` instead, or more legibly `if( !uid && email_eval)`

Comment: OMG, I knew that but I just did not see the single = sign there.  Thanks.  

And plus +1 virtually for the legibly, I like that syntax.